# How to Word-like-merge columns or rows of a data frame for displaying purposes in R?

Tags: r, merge

I wrote a function (adfcs; **a**ugmented **D**ickey-**F**uller that takes the usage of **c**ommon **s**ample into account during ADF test). With its result, I can prepare the table of ADF Statistics of the Raw Variables (Stationarity table) in MS Word like that:
[[In ADF regression, the results were given in the order of “both drift and time trend (dt)”, “drift without time trend (d)” and “no drift, no time trend(-)”. Whether the drift and time trend coefficients in the ADF regressions is significant was specified with “s” (significant) that is given after the values of ADF statistics; if the coefficients were significant (Pr(>|t|)<0,05) “s” was written; if not, nothing was put to the related cell. "X"s are the shaded cells in Word since there can be no values in those cells]]

```
              TABLE.    ADF STATISTICS OF THE RAW VARIABLES

Variable Type tstat   SignfofConstant SignfofTimeTrend ProbValue
................................................................
          dt   -2.75                        s            0.2244
 Var1      d   -2.25        s               X            0.1907
           -   -0.59        X               X            0.4520
...............................................................
          dt   -2.75        s                            0.2244
 Var2      d   -2.25        s               X            0.1907
           -   -0.59        X               X            0.4520
 ...............................................................
```

I wanna write a function (adfcstable) in R that will return the above table (as a data frame) in R. The above table is in essence 7x6 table where rows 2,3,4 and rows 5,6,7 of column 1 is merged. i.e. the data frame df will be like this: df[2,1]=df[3,1]=df[4,1]=Var1, but when I print df, I must get Var1 only 1 time as is shown in the above table. Can this (Word-like-merge displaying of a data frame) be performed in R via coding?

I appreciate in advance for any help presented.

**Reproducible Example:**

```
> df <- data.frame(c("Var1","Var1","Var1","Var2","Var2","Var2"),c(1,2,3,5,2,1))
> colnames(df) <- c("Variable","Col2")
> df
   Variable Col2
1     Var1    1
2     Var1    2
3     Var1    3
4     Var2    5
5     Var2    2
6     Var2    1
```

But, I want:

```
   Variable Col2
1             1
2     Var1    2
3             3
4             5
5     Var2    2
6             1
```

"df[1,1] <- NULL" gave error. "df[1,1] <- NA" resulted "" in the [1,1]. Also, df[1,1] <- "" and df[1,1] <- c("") did not work. Let nothing appear in [1,1] cell.

Comment: Please consider providing a reproducible example/dataset ...

Comment: I would suggest you keep your data stored in a data.frame and write a print or summary function that will print the desired table. This is possible, but some pre-calculations and inserting blank cells would be necessary.

Comment: If you want to modify `df$Variable`, you need to make sure its not `factor` class. For example adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating your data set, e.g. `df <- data.frame(Variable = c("Var1","Var1","Var1","Var2","Var2","Var2"),Col2 = c(1,2,3,5,2,1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. Then, all you have to do (it seems) is just `df$Variable[df$Col2 != 2] <- ""`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, Thanks a lot. stringsAsFactors solved most of the question: The " <-"" " assignment worked when class(df[,1])="character", but not class(df[,1])="factor" as you specified. I thought and guessed that perhaps there can be a function like merge(df[2:4,1]) and merge(df[5:7,1]) that performs without this kind of tricky assignments.

Comment: I don't see any need in `merge` in your example. You probably should create a fully reproducible example.

Comment: @Dave, Thanks. YOU REALLY SOLVED COMPLETELY: stringsAsFactors solved most of the question: The " <-"" " assignment worked when class(df[,1])="character", but not class(df[,1])="factor" as you specified. Also, "!=2" logic in your reply, completely corresponds to "!="d"" in my question. Since there is only 3 option (dt, d, -) and the deleted ones in col1 corresponds to only (dt,-), your logic finish it at all. If R team does a general function like merge(df[2:4,1]) and merge(df[5:7,1]) then without this kind of tricky assgs & logic that worked in this ques, the other probs are solved as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved by David Arenburg]

```
> df <- data.frame(Variable = c("Var1","Var1","Var1","Var2","Var2","Var2"),Type = c("dt","d","-","dt","d","-"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df
  Variable Type
1     Var1   dt
2     Var1    d
3     Var1    -
4     Var2   dt
5     Var2    d
6     Var2    -
> df$Variable[df$Type != "d"] <- ""
> df
  Variable Type
1            dt
2     Var1    d
3             -
4            dt
5     Var2    d
6             -
```

Luckily, the centered position after merging is just the level of "d" rows. Hence, solution worked for this case. If there were 4 repeated item in Type column then centering position would be the one between 2nd and 3rd rows of the merged cells, and in that case another solution would be needed.